# How to get the index of 'th' element using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have the following HTML code and need to determine the index of "Number of Strings" using the `<span>` id. I'm using Nokogiri to parse the HTML and get the row.

```
doc = Nokogiri::parse(myfile.html)
table = doc.xpath("//span[@id='NumStrs']/../../..")
row = table.xpath["tr[1]"]
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<tr>
<th id ="langframe">
<span id="cabinet">
Cabinet</span>
</th>
<th id ="langbb1">
<span id="bb1">
BB1</span>
</th>
<th id ="langbb2">
<span id="bb2">
BB2</span>
</th>
<th id ="langtemp">
<span id="Temp">
Temperature</span>
</th>
<th id="langstrs">
<span id="StringsPresent">
Strings Present</span>
</th>
<th id="langmstrQty">
<span id="NumStrs">
Number of Strings</span>
</th>
</tr>
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: index with respect to what? What should the index of 'Number of Strings' be?

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it using Ruby's `with_index` combined with a `select`:

```
require 'nokogiri'  # => true

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<tr>
<th id ="langframe">
<span id="cabinet">
Cabinet</span>
</th>
<th id ="langbb1">
<span id="bb1">
BB1</span>
</th>
<th id ="langbb2">
<span id="bb2">
BB2</span>
</th>
<th id ="langtemp">
<span id="Temp">
Temperature</span>
</th>
<th id="langstrs">
<span id="StringsPresent">
Strings Present</span>
</th>
<th id="langmstrQty">
<span id="NumStrs">
Number of Strings</span>
</th>
</tr>
EOT

th_idx = doc.search('th').to_enum.with_index.select { |th, idx| th.text['Number of Strings'] }.first
```

That returns:

```
th_idx 
# => [#(Element:0x3fe72d83cd3c {
#       name = "th",
#       attributes = [
#         #(Attr:0x3fe72d4440f4 { name = "id", value = "langmstrQty" })],
#       children = [
#         #(Text "\n"),
#         #(Element:0x3fe72d43c3e0 {
#           name = "span",
#           attributes = [
#             #(Attr:0x3fe72d439b04 { name = "id", value = "NumStrs" })],
#           children = [ #(Text "\nNumber of Strings")]
#           }),
#         #(Text "\n")]
#       }),
#     5]
```

The index is:

```
th_idx.last # => 5
```

Once you have `th_idx`, you can easily access parent or child nodes to find out about its surroundings:

```
th_node = th_idx.first
th_node['id'] # => "langmstrQty"
th_node.at('span')
# => #(Element:0x3fd5110286d8 {
#      name = "span",
#      attributes = [
#        #(Attr:0x3fd511021b6c { name = "id", value = "NumStrs" })],
#      children = [ #(Text "\nNumber of Strings")]
#      })
th_node.at('span')['id'] # => "NumStrs"
```

[`with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) adds a 0-based index to each element passed to it. [`to_enum`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-to_enum) is required because `search` returns a NodeSet, which isn't an enumerator so `to_enum` returns that.

If you want a 1-based index use `with_index(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working, not sure if this is the efficient way to do it.. but it works

```
header = table.xpath("tr[1]")
value = header.xpath("//span[@id='#{id}']").text
index = header.search('th//text()').collect {|text| text.to_s.strip}.reject(&:empty?).index(value)+1
```